# R Selectively replacing elements of a dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a column in a dataframe of variable names like so:

```
tb <- tibble(Variable = c("var1", "var2", "var3"))
```

I also have a named vector of new names I want to replace certain cells in the column with:

```
new_names <- c(var1 = "VariableOne")
```

I tried this based on my googling:

```
tb %>% mutate(Variable = new_names[Variable])

# A tibble: 3 x 1
  Variable   
  <chr>      
1 VariableOne
2 NA         
3 NA
```

It almost works, but I don't want R to replace the cells with NA if they are not in my new_names vector. In that case, I want to keep the original name. How do I do this?

Comment: We can create a condition with `case_when`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without changing the OP's method, and option is to `coalesce` with 'Variable' to replace the `NA` elements with the original 'Variable' value

```
tb %>% 
    mutate(Variable =coalesce(new_names[Variable], Variable))
# A tibble: 3 x 1
#  Variable   
#  <chr>      
#1 VariableOne
#2 var2       
#3 var3
```

---

Or another option is `case_when`

```
tb %>%
   mutate(Variable = case_when(Variable %in% names(new_names) ~ 
                         new_names[Variable], TRUE ~ Variable))
```

Comment: Thank you akrun! coalesce is a really elegant solution that I didnt know was out there.

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr)

tb <- tibble(Variable = c("var1", "var2", "var3"))

tb %>% mutate(Variable = replace(Variable, Variable == "var1", "VariableOne"))
```